# Add 2 exception in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, ioexception

I created this class with 1 try and 2 catch, the first one checks if the value is correct, the second one I want it to check in input if the value is int otherwise it throws the exception in the catch. I'm working on eclipse and IOException marks it as an error why?

```
class eccez {

    public eccez() {
        int a = 15;
        int s = 0;
        int risultato = 0;

        System.out.println("Inserisci valore divisore");

        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            s = input.nextInt();
            risultato = a / s;
        } catch(ArithmeticException y) {
            System.out.println("trovato errore aritmetico");
            return;
        } catch(IOException x) {
            System.out.println("trovato errore");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Risultato " + risultato);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error does Eclipse indicate?

Comment: IOException cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Control-shift-O in the text editor, you're simply missing an import statement.

Comment: you need to import the class. Also your `eccez` method is missing a return type, use `void`.

Comment: Control-S to save and recompile.

Comment: Don't catch `ArithmeticException`. You can simply check if `s == 0` before the division. Exceptions should only be caught when you can't predict the outcome in advance.

Comment: @f1sh That's a badly named constructor. Class name isn't capitalized.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica oh god, it's badly named enought to fool me

Comment: If the next token of input is not an int a java.util.InputMismatchException is thrown, not an IOException. So for your purpose in the second catch you could catch java.util.InputMismatchException